# Can someone explain how can I use Accelerated Node in bsc chain to validate my transactions?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, bsc

I wanted to know what are the Accelerated Node in bsc chain and after reading the docs I got that Accelerated Nodes are some special nodes provided by bsc which a user can choose to validate their transaction, So I was trying to implement it manually on the testnet

I was trying to access one of the Accelerated Node provided by bsc testnet
SO these are the two nodes
1.)testnet-dex-atlantic.binance.org
2.)testnet-dex-asiapacific.binance.org

I just wanted to know how to access this